# ¿Cuáles son las relaciones de subtipo que existen entre las clases Iterable, Collection, Set, List, LinkedList, Queue, Deque, Map, HasMap?

Tags: java

¿Cuáles son las relaciones de subtipo que existen entre las clases Iterable, Collection, Set, List, LinkedList, Queue, Deque, Map, HasMap?

Intenté hacer un esquema pero creo que cometí errores en la clase HashMap, por ejemplo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me ha salido muy bien la imagen pero...

Un poco de explicación - excepto LinkedList y HashMap, que son clases, el resto son interfaces.

Cuando quieres saber la herencia de alguna clase lo más sencillo es mirar [aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). Y ahí ves:

> public class HashMap extends AbstractMap implements
>   Map, Cloneable, Serializable

Pinchas [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) y te sale esto:

> public interface Map

y ya no hay más hacia arriba.

Y lo mismo con cualquier clase.

O pinchas en el [tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/package-tree.html) y ahí lo ves todo, lo que pasa que es un poco más complicado de seguir porque hay muchas clases. Aun así es útil.

Espero haberte ayudado.